# Transition on toggle between two images

Tags: html, css, font-awesome

I have a `div` element that contains two images. Using CSS `:hover`, I toggle the display of the two images (FontAwesome icons)

```html
<div class="alternating-content-item-content alternating-content-item__content col-md-6">
  <div class="alternating-content-item-content__padding">
    <h3 class="alternating-content-item-content__heading">Trading</h3>
    <p class="alternating-content-item-content__blurb">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. </p>
    <a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank" class="alternating-content-item-content__link">
      Read More
      <i class="fa fa-chevron-right fa-hover-hidden read-more-icon"></i>
      <i class="fa fa-arrow-right fa-hover-show read-more-icon"></i>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

My CSS is

```css
.fa.fa-hover-show {
    display: none;
}

&:hover {
    .fa.fa-hover-hidden {
        display: none;
    }

    .fa.fa-hover-show {
        display: inline-block;
    }
}
```

How can I add the transition/transformation to the div hover event to make a smooth animation between the two fa icons?

Comment: Transitions/Animations doesn't work on `display` property. Use `opacity` or `visibility` property to show/hide icons.

Comment: What is the `&` selector? :/

Comment: @UncaughtTypeError OP is working with SCSS; I guess.

Comment: @MohammadUsman Riiiiight - I see those nested CSS declarations.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a smooth animation you should use `opacity`. For example:

```
button {
    transition: opacity 0.5s linear;
}

.fa.fa-hover-show {
    opacity: 0
}

button:hover {
    .fa.fa-hover-hidden {
        opacity: 0
    }

    .fa.fa-hover-show {
        opacity: 1
    }
}
```